# Looking for faster way for row by row looping and transposing data in Python data frames

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, transpose

I have just recently started learning coding and wrote the following code in Python to transpose large dataset row by row.

The code works fine but is unfortunately somewhat slow and takes roughly 15 minutes to complete. Transposing the whole dataset at once does not work as it creates unnecessary rows to dataset as they can differ slightly company by company.

```
for index, row in subset.iterrows():
    temp = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(pd.io.json.json_normalize(subset.Financials[a:b], max_level = 4)))
    temp['symbol'] = (row['Symbol'])
    #print(subset['Symbol'][a:b])
    #IncomeStatements.append(temp)
    
    IncomeStatements = pd.concat([IncomeStatements, temp])
    
    print(row['Symbol'], " | ", a, end="\r")
    #print(a)
    
    a = a+1
    b = b+1
```

The data has the following structure and each row contains the financials and a stock symbol:

[image: Picture of the data]

Picture of the desired result.

[image: Desired result]

I have tried some other methods such as apply with little success and all the help would be much appreciated.

Comment: May be you could use 'numpy.transpose()' function from numpy library.

Comment: Please, add some example of the data to work with and your expected desired, preferably not images. See [Minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)